# Symfony2: SerializerBuilder and Memory

Tags: symfony, serialization

I am working on a small API with Symfony 2 and I am having problems with the serialization of data.

I have this code in my controller:

```
// Create the $serializer
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
// Put the serialized data in $jsonContent
$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($products, 'json');
// Generate a Json Response
$response = new Response($jsonContent);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

But I have more than 1000 rows in my `$products` collection, and it seems that my server doesn't have enough memory to handle that, this code returns `HTTP Error 500`. Here are the Apache log line:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 75 bytes) in /var/www/blog/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php on line 152
```

How could I do to optimize memory (and make work my code) in this case?

Thanks a lot for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can increase the the `memory_limit` property of your php.ini

it seems to be 128M right now, just increase it to 1G

how to find out where my php.ini is ?

add `phpInfo()` to for example your AppKernel.php, display it, search for `php.ini`

and you find sth. like

Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/php.ini

if you dont want to globaly increase the memory limit, you could also set the property with htaccess or directly from php